# How to use get_text() method for only extract heading in Beautiful Soup python

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I want to extract only all headings from this page, but when I use `get_text()` method the error occurs. What is the solution of this example. Explain with examples. I run this code on python3.4 version.

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "http://www.brecorder.com/"

urls = [url]
visited = [url]
while len(urls)>0:
     try:
          htmltext = urllib.request.urlopen(urls[0]).read()
          response = htmltext
     except:
          print(urls[0])

     soup = BeautifulSoup(response)
     urls.pop(0)
     soup = soup.find_all("h2")
     print(soup.get_text())
```

Error is:
AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'get_text'

Or if I replace this line

```
soup = soup.find_all("h2")
```

from this

```
soup = soup.select("h2")
```

The following error occur:

```
AttributeError: `list` object has no attribute `get_text`
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to apply a method defined on *individual elements* on a whole set or list of them.

Both `soup.select()` and `soup.find_all()` return a *list* of elements, not just one. You'd use a loop:

```
for element in soup.select('h2'):
    print(element.get_text())
```

or you can apply the method to each element in a list comprehension, to produce a new list:

```
print([element.get_text() for element in soup.select('h2')])
```

Demo:

```
>>> import urllib.request
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> url = "http://www.brecorder.com/"
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(url))
>>> print([element.get_text() for element in soup.select('h2')])
["Editor's choice", 'Op/Ed ', 'Business & Finance ', 'Markets ', 'Taxation ', 'BR Research ', 'Cotton & Textile ', 'Entertainment ', 'Currency Converter ', 'KSE Market Live ', 'Sports\t\t ']
```

Comment: But i want to extract all heading from all links in this page.

Comment: like a crawler... So what can I do?

Comment: @Anaya: you *are* extracting headings. If you have a follow-up query, you can post a new question.

Comment: @Anaya: if you want to extract links, extract `<a>` elements; soup.select('a[href]')` and get their `href` attributes. This is all covered in the BeautifulSoup documentation however.